# Disabling clicking when using .fadeOut() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a card game. When the user clicks the card, the card fades out. However, at the moment, there is a serious bug. The user can click one card multiple times, adding multiple card numbers to an array (essentially picking lots of cards).

How can i resolve this? Here is my code so far:

```
$(clicked_id).fadeOut('fast');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: entire code:

```
<script>
var cardsPicked = new Array;

var suits = ["&hearts;", "&diams;", "&clubs;", "&spades;"];
var king = 0;
var numbers = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
var cardRules = ["Waterfall", "You", "Me", "Girls", "Thumbmaster", "Guys", "Heaven", "Mate", "Rhyme", "Catagories", "Make a rule", "Question master", "Pour your drink!"];

var currentId;

function getCard(clicked_id) {

    clicked_id = "#" + clicked_id;

    $(clicked_id).fadeOut('fast');

    var newCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * 13) + 1);

    var newSuit = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    var currentCard;
    var x = document.getElementById("pick");
    var rules = document.getElementById("rules");
    var kings = document.getElementById("kings");
    var currentCards = document.getElementById("currentCard");

    if (cardsPicked.indexOf(numbers[newCard - 1] + " " + suits[newSuit - 1]) == -1) {

        if (numbers[newCard - 1] == "K" && king < 4) {
            king = king + 1;
        }
        if (king == 4) {
            king = "All kings found!";
            alert("Fourth king picked. Down the jug!");
        }
        cardsPicked.push(numbers[newCard - 1] + " " + suits[newSuit - 1]);
        for (count = 0; count < cardsPicked.length; count++)
        currentRule = cardRules[newCard - 1];

        x.innerHTML = cardsPicked;
        currentCards.innerHTML = numbers[newCard - 1] + " " + suits[newSuit - 1];
        rules.innerHTML = currentRule;
        kings.innerHTML = king;

    } else {

        getCard();
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the code that is used to add the clicked card to the array

Comment: @SamStone, how is the event binded?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(clicked_id).off().fadeOut('fast');
```

---

In case the event is called by inline `onclick` :

```
$(clicked_id).prop("onclick", "").off().fadeOut('fast');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G5SVC/1/)

Comment: @ZoltanToth, By the way, how can you know the way OP is binding the event handler?

Comment: It still adds numbers to the array when you're clicking as it fades away

Comment: I don't see the `fadeOut` part anywhere in your code - where do you unbind the click event?

Comment: I see.. you probably triggering the click with `onclick`. In that case remove it like this - http://jsfiddle.net/G5SVC/1/

Comment: @Alexander You seem to be right - the OP is most likely using `onclick`. I've added an update if that's the case

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove the click event on the element, then do the fade out effect with a callback function which will reattach the click event.

```
$('#clicked_id').off('click').fadeOut('fast', function () {
    $('#clicked_id').on('click');
});
```

This is completely untested and just a theory but it might work!